# How to deregister delegate handler during runtime

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, delegates

I am registering delegate handler using unity during the initialization of webapi,during runtime i need to deregister the same handler,how can i achieve this?
I am developing the application in c#

Answer (score 1):

It would be helpful if you can update the question with some code which you have written to add the handler. 
Anyway to remove a handler you can simply use -= operator.

**To Remove handler**

`backgroundWorker.DoWork -= mehtodName;`

**To Add handler** I think you might be using something similar to below code to add the handler.?

`backgroundWorker.DoWork += mehtodName;`